# Execution failed for task ':library:cinteropRealmSwiftIos' when adding RealmSwift to kotlin multiplaform library project

Tags: gradle, realm, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to add RealmSwift as a dependency for the iOS target of my Kotlin multiplaform library project. I get this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':library:cinteropRealmSwiftIos'.
> Process 'command '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I have no clue about what is this gradle task "cinteropRealmSwiftIos", but it always fails there with a generic exit code and no useful message.

Here is my `build.gradle.kts`:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")

    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
}

kotlin {
    val iOSTarget: (String, KotlinNativeTarget.() -> Unit) -> KotlinNativeTarget =
        if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") == true)
            ::iosArm64
        else
            ::iosX64
    android()
    iOSTarget("ios") {
        binaries {
        }
    }

    version = "1.0" // Pod version
    cocoapods {
        // Configure fields required by CocoaPods.
        summary = "Some description for a Kotlin/Native module"
        homepage = "Link to a Kotlin/Native module homepage"
        frameworkName = "MyLibrary"
        // RealmSwift needs a "recent" deployment target.
        ios.deploymentTarget = "12.0"

        pod("RealmSwift") {
            version = "~> 10.5"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting
    }
}

android { /* Android Config */}
```

I'm using Kotlin version "1.4.31" and Cocoa Pods version "1.10.1".

Answer (score 0):

According to the pod name, I would say that this is not a good idea. Kotlin/Native does not support direct interoperability with Swift, only through Objective-C(see more details [here][1]). Maybe some other pod will be more appropriate

P.S, as I found in [this][2] repository, the Realm team is working on a Kotlin Multiplatform version. Probably worth checking out if you're interested in using this library for your KMM projects.